# How to do incremental HMAC SHA1 in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, hmacsha1

I saw there are different articles about calculating HMAC SHA1 in Swift but actually I'm looking for a way to calculate it incrementally.

Let's say I'm receiving a big amount of data from a tcp socket and at the end I will receive the HMAC SHA1 too.
Now I need to compare the HMAC I received with the one calculate.

What I would like to do is **calculating** the HMAC SHA1 **while the data is coming** instead of waiting for all the data to arrive and only then calculate my version of the HMAC SHA1..

In C I already did this (I can post the code if someone is interested in) but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in Swift.

many thanks and regards.

Comment: The code in Swift is very close to the code in C (using CommonCrypto's CCHmac). See RNCryptor for an example: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/blob/master/RNCryptor.swift#L650-L673

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very similar indeed!